# From Jquery Ajax get prev, next

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I want to load content from the DB on particular div by click on next and prev..
I am getting the array say for an example like below, I don't understand how to code for Prev and next!

This for a product page by clicking Next, Prev shows related products!!

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7319
    [1] => 38089
    [2] => 34203
    [3] => 35604
    [4] => 36209
    [5] => 34978
    [6] => 35196
    [7] => 35856
    [8] => 39841
    [9] => 23944
    [10] => 38239
    [11] => 34866
)
```

HTML

```
<a class="ajx" name="prev" >Prev</a>
<a class="ajx" name="next" >Next</a>
```

JS

```
 $(function () {

        $('.ajx').on('click', function(){

        var rel_cars_array = <?php echo json_encode($rel_cars_ajax); ?> 

        var data = {'sale_id' :<?php echo current($rel_cars_ajax);?>};

            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              data: data,
              url: '<?php echo base_url();?>ajaxdetail',
              success: function (response) {
                $("#detail-con").html(response);
              }
            }); 
        });
});
```

Comment: Refer the "ajax pagination" related searches

Comment: I have searched maximum around 8 hours then after only I post the question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

JS

```
  $(function () {     

    $('.ajx').on('click', function(){   
    var rel_cars_array = <?php echo json_encode($rel_cars_ajax); ?> 
    rel_cars_array.unshift(<?php echo $car["salable_registered_id"];?>);

    if(typeof start == 'undefined'){
        start = rel_cars_array[0];
    }

    if($(this).attr('name')=='prev'){
        var prev = rel_cars_array[($.inArray(start, rel_cars_array) - 1 + rel_cars_array.length) % rel_cars_array.length];
        start = prev;   
    }
    if($(this).attr('name')=='next'){
        var next = rel_cars_array[($.inArray(start, rel_cars_array) + 1) % rel_cars_array.length];
        start = next;       
    }

    var data = {'sale_id' : start };

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data: data,
          url: '<?php echo base_url();?>ajaxdetail',
          success: function (response) {
            $("#detail-con").html(response);
          }
        }); 
    });
});
```